# When is it necessary to convert data types in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Visual Basic 2010 (Express). I can best give this by example...

If I take a string from a textbox and assign it to an integer variable, I'm under the impression that you're supposed to use CInt to explicitly convert the contents to an integer.

```
intMyCount = CInt(txtUserInput.Text)
```

However, if I don't do that, it still seems to work. Similarly, if I have an integer and concatenate it into a label's text property, it still works:

```
lblResults.Text = intMyCount & " number of times."
```

rather than using `intMyCount.ToString.`

Why does it work? Is VB doing implicit conversions when possible? Are there examples where not explicitly converting with .ToString or using CInt would cause unexpected results?

Comment: Question looks more beautiful when you format your code.

Comment: @Shoban - thanks. Must be getting tired :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done using late-binding, and it's dangerous because if the conversion ever fails (and there's lots of cases where your first example could fail) it ends up in an exception at runtime.  To get the compiler to enforce safer casting, turn `Option Strict On`.

Additionally, most of the time you don't want to use `CInt()` to convert your string to int.  Instead, prefer `Integer.Parse()` or `Integer.TryParse()`.

Comment: +1. Additionally, OP asked for examples where not explicitly converting could cause unexpected results. The classic example would be where you wish to control the interpretation of strings in terms of regional settings. E.g. you always want the string to be interpreted with dot as decimal separator rather than taking account of the PC regional settings.

Comment: Is there a reasonable explanation (or logical explanation) why there's both CInt() and Integer.Parse()? Doesn't that increase the probability of errors when creating the program if there are subtle but different ways to do something as common as translating a string to a number?

Comment: @Bart - CInt() serves two purposes: backwards compatibility to vb6 and cases where you _know_ the input will be formatted correctly (ie, a machine to machine data transfer).

Answer (score 1):

Some languages handle string concatenation easily like this for the non-casting to string.  Some also handle non-casting to numeric types to do calculations.  Some languages don't handle it at all.  However as a best-practice, I would always cast the variable to the type you want to avoid issues with improper input types.